# How do I make eclipse (Indigo) collapse empty (parent) packages?

Tags: eclipse

What I want to do is simply use the eclipse package explorer in hierarchical view but with empty packages being collapsed so I don't have to open 5+ packages to find the first Java file.

I'm not even sure how I did it in previous versions, but I've never had any trouble finding it before, it just seems to be gone now. I have a feeling there was a "flatten hierarchy" tick-box somewhere.

To clarify I get this:

```
com
  example
    etc
      file1.java
```

Rather than:

```
com.example.etc
  file1.java
```

I'm using Eclipse Indigo (v. 3.7.1)

[image: Requested settings screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the problem actually was, but I couldn't get it fixed until I gave up altogether and reinstalled the OS (it was a fresh install anyway), and eclipse. It was completely fine after that. :\

Comment: @hariszhr None of the other things suggested here worked at all, so I don't know what you expect from me. They're certainly not the right answer when they didn't work at all.

Comment: Then you should keep this question open :) Someone might post a better answer.

Comment: @hariszhr That's not really feasible. There's no way to verify whether or not anyone else's answer was better at this point apart from going back in time and trying it before I reinstalled my OS. There's little to nothing that would allow anyone with a similar issue to know whether it's in fact the same issue or not. The other answers are still available and may still help others, but it doesn't change anything for the original issue. I don't even use Eclipse any more, there's really not anything to be gained here.

Answer (score 7):

Open the View menu (small triangle in top right corner), open filters and check Empty parent packages.

In most cases it works, but in case of existing projects it does not always work as expected. If you seem to have troubles, try to export the project, remove it, then re-add the exported version (or re-checkout from your VCS).

Comment: I've tried the empty parent packages filter, good call on re-importing the project, but unfortunately the same result.

Comment: It's interesting, because that works for me as expected in all my workspaces and Eclipse versions...

Comment: To be honest there could be a problem with my eclipse install (although it's a completely fresh install), because for some reason any extensions I install don't seem to appear or do anything at all (such as Subclipse, AnyEdit, CheckStyle), I can't even see their options in the settings dialogue.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as the OP. The description of "Empty parent packages" describes exactly what we are trying to achieve. Unfortunately, in my case hiding empty parent packages was already checked but does not seem to have any effect :( (disable and re-enable did not change it either). Since in my case it is a very install of Eclipse 4.2.1, I would say this is just a bug :(.

Comment: Sometimes I have experienced that if applied to an open project. As I have stated it in my answer, exporting the project, removing it and re-importing it usually fixes this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the view filter is engaged properly, perhaps your source folders are not as "empty" as you think.

For example, on Apple OS X, Eclipse will detect .DS_STORE entires along your src/package/hierarchy, making the parent packages technically non-empty.

Delete any such hidden files and refresh your project.

Comment: Are you aware this question already has an accepted answer? Check it out :) Welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: this answer helped me, my problem was a hidden desktop.ini file from windows

Answer (score 2):

Window - Preferences - Java - Appearance - Abbreviate package names

And enter the following rule:

com.example.etc={cee}

Comment: Nothing I enter in that box seems to make even the slightest difference. I also never needed to enter any rules for this in the past, it *should* be really straight forward. :\

Comment: Have you checked the checkbox? It works fine on my install (same version as yours). Could you post a screenshot of these preferences and of your package explorer view?

Comment: I can, but I don't know the best way of uploading it. I've definitely checked the "Abbreviate package names" checkbox. The actual package structure is `net.ubiquity.cdm`, I've tried entering `net.ubiquity={cee}`, `net.ubiquity=ubq`, `net.ubiquity={JDT}`, etc. Mostly grasping at straws, but nothing changed at all. `src/java` is merged, but everything below that is one entry per package.

Comment: Edit your question, and use the "Image" button in the toolbar of the edit box

Answer (score 1):

Click on the arrow at the top right of the "Package explorer" and choose "Package presentation -> flat"

Comment: As I said, I wanted it hierarchical, not flat. I just want to have only one entry for `com.example.etc` rather than 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart Eclipse once in a while. I had trouble getting it to work, and after an Eclipse restart it suddenly was working again.